# Sorting a table loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I have created a table from a csv file, with ajax.  I would like to be able to sort the rows by columns.  I have found ways using JS to accomplish this with hard coded tables, however I am unable to transfer this to the csv table.  I have tried examples from W3schools, and attempted using custom methods like [Sorttable](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#ajaxtables) by Stuart Langridge

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url:"data/surveys.csv",
        datatype:"text",
        success:function(data){
          var moon_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
          var table_data = '<table id="myTable" class="sortable table table-bordered table-striped">';
          for (var count = 0; count < moon_data.length; count++){
            var cell_data = moon_data[count].split(",");
            if (count === 0){
              table_data += '<thead>';

            }else{
              table_data += '<tbody id="myTableContent" style="border: 1px solid #dddddd;">';

            }
            table_data += '<tr style="border: 1px solid #dddddd;">';
            for(var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++){
              if (count === 0 ){
                // Load the header
                table_data += '<th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; background: rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.6);">' + cell_data[cell_count] + cell_count +'</th>';
              }
              else{
                // Load the table body
                if(count % 2 == 1){
                  table_data += '<td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; min-width:70px; background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.6);">' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
                }
                else{
                  table_data += '<td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; min-width:70px; background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.6);">' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
                }
              }
            }
              table_data += '</tr>';
            if (count === 0){
              table_data += '</thead>';
            }
          }
          table_data += '</tbody>';
          table_data += '</table>';
          $('#moon_table').html(table_data);
        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

I believe the problem is that when the browser processes:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {

            var moon_table_object = document.getElementById(myTable);
            console.log(moon_table_object);
            sorttable.makeSortable(moon_table_object);

        }, 4000);
    }
    </script>
```

the log returns null.  This tells me that according to document.getElementById(myTable), this has yet to be created.  As you can tell I have added a timer and onload to see if waiting several seconds after the table has been fully loaded would help, but it does not.
I am receiving

> sorttable.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
>       at Object.makeSortable (sorttable.js:43)
>       at (index):84
>   in the console afterward but I am pretty sure that this will be solved when moon_table_object passes the table correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you give me your csv?

Comment: You can use datatable for this type functionality.

https://datatables.net/

Comment: I don't see that `myTable` ever gets set. Maybe you meant `"myTable"`?

Comment: http://moon.aaronmaynard.com/data/surveys.csv
Is the file that I am reading. 

datatables allows me to load them another way which I believe I can make work. thank for that. HirenRaiyani

@Ouroborus yes, I had it as myTable for testing it with one preloaded. Question still applies